# error parsing xml unbound prefix in android

Tags: android, layout, xml-parsing

Trying to rotate an image.
It gets the error text as error parsing Xml unbound prefix.
I tried the code from here

http://go-lambda.blogspot.in/2012/02/rotary-knob-widget-on-android.html

```
<com.example.Rotation 
android:id="@+id/jogView"
android:layout_width="300px"
android:layout_height="300px"
android:layout_gravity="center"
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<com.example.Rotation 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/jogView"
     android:layout_width="300px"
     android:layout_height="300px"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
/>
```